# Android: why does fragment toast not fire when fragmentdialog is dismissed?

Tags: android, android-fragments, datepicker

I have code in my Activity to launch a DatePicker in a fragment.  The DatePickerDialog allows the user to select a date.  Then I'd like the DatePickerDialog to close (onDismiss) and show a toast.  Nothing happens.  What am I missing here?

fragment file:

```
public class SaveDatePickerFrag extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

Calendar c;
int year = 0, month = 0, day = 0;

public SaveDatePickerFrag() {
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

    c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog picker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
            this, year, month, day);
    return picker;
 }

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
     calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,month);
     calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,day);
     txtDate = (EditText) getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().findViewById(R.id.EditText);
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
 }

  public void onDismiss(final DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
    if (getActivity() !=null) {
        // The below Toast reminds the user to click Save to proceed.
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "If done, click the Save button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you doing this in background thread?

Comment: Not sure how to answer that.  The Activity loads the Fragment so the user can enter a date from a DatePicker dialog.  I'd like to show a toast when the user is done entering the date as the dialog and fragment are dismissed and the user returns to the Activity and main UI.

Comment: Show your complete class

Comment: probably getActivity() is null and hence the toast does not show up. Try debugging the code and check the values in ur onDismiss method.

Comment: I don't have any good experience with debugging.  Can you provide any direction on how to proceed?  I understand the goal but don't know what to do to set it up.

Comment: Write **super.onDismiss(dialog)** after the if condition, may be it will work.

Comment: @Nigam Patro:  no luck but I appreciate the try.

Comment: In the constructor pass object of Context and use that context object instead of getActivity().

Comment: Ok I will try, but please provide example so I set up correctly.

Comment: just try this.. show the toast outside the if condition. If it appears then u will know that the getActivity() call returns null and hence the problem.

Comment: u can have a look at this for debugging ur application. http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html

Comment: I put the Toast in the OnDateSet section and still no toast.  Any ideas?